# Why syntax error near unexpected token `fi' is coming

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

This is my simple script but it is saying that syntax error near unexpected token `fi'

```
mysql --user=root --password= erpint -B -e "select * from user_info;" | sed      "s/'/\'/;s/\t/\",\"/g;s/^/\"/;s/$/\"/;s/\n//g" > /home/mayuri/detail.csv
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
mutt -s "Mutt attach" srini@erpint.com -a /home/mayuri/detail.csv < /home/mayuri/trials.txt
fi
```

Comment: Which shell did you specify in the shebang?

Comment: bash shell @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams

Answer (score 0):

If it's a bash script, make sure you have included "#!/bin/bash" on the first line of your script file.

Answer (score 0):

When attaching single or multiple files, separating filenames and recipient addresses with `--` is mandatory:

```
mutt -s "Mutt attach" -a /home/mayuri/detail.csv -- srini@erpint.com < /home/mayuri/trials.txt
```

See `man mutt` fore more about:

> **mutt** *[-nx] [-e cmd] [-F file] [-s subj] [-b addr] [-c addr]* **[-a file [...] --] addr** *[...] < message*

Also, be sure that first line of the script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
```